# MFMailComposeViewController delegate not called

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm not able to call Mail composer delegate method even if I'm writing below code:

```
-(void)openMailComposerInViewController:(UIViewController *)hostController{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"Test Email";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@test.com"];

    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen

    [hostController presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
    mailController = hostController;
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

## pragma mark - Mail

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
  switch (result)
  {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Close the Mail Interface
[mailController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

**I do not want to call mail composer on self**

However, my delegate is not getting called. Please help. The application crashed on clicking on Cancel or Send mail button

Comment: Can you provide your crash log?

Comment: Why are you setting `mailController = hostController` after presenting the mail controller?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem, and my problem was I had the following code:

```
self.mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
self.mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
```

I was setting the delegate before I initialized the mailComposer object. I just switched those 2 lines to this and it worked:

```
 self.mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
 self.mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of ARC, I was losing the viewcontroller in which the delegate was written so it was not gettting called. Below code helped me fix the issue:

```
+(MailComposer *)sharedInstance
{

  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMailComposer = [[MailComposer alloc]init];
  });
  return sharedMailComposer;

}
```

Then I used the above instance while calling the MailComposerViewController

```
    [[MailComposer sharedInstance] openMailComposerInViewController:[(UINavigationController *)moduleRouter.container topViewController]];
```

It Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

your class instance must be same for setMailComposeDelegate and presentViewController.

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = hostController;

[hostController presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```